# Build or Compile Webkit on Windows7 64bit

Tags: windows, google-chrome, webkit, cygwin

I'm trying to just build webkit on windows. As usual I started with [webkit site](https://www.webkit.org/building/tools.html) and trying to get developer tools setup. I'm struck basically at the cygwin Installation itself.

The [cygwin-downloader](http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/Tools/CygwinDownloader/cygwin-downloader.zip) gets all the packages and runs the setup normally.

As per the installation instructions, I selected the Install from Local Directory Option (cygwin install and source package directories are different).

There was some initial turbulance in finding the packages, somehow i could let it find the packages. The screen looks like this now.

[image: cygwin_select-package]

I selected the packages (all) and then proceeded with next. It just ran very fast and exited saying nothing needs to be installed. It looked like this.

[image: cygwin_nothing_to_be_installed]

After I ran the cygwin shorcut from the desktop its shouting something is missing.
[image: cygwin_missing_shorcut]

I don't understand what am I missing here. Also at some link it says we need a port to build webkit. If thats the case, how does anyone port webkit to their applications without building the webkit alone?

I know this is not a programming question. but this will help most of the people who are taking baby steps in understanding and build WebKit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2014-04/msg00067.html), it's seems a [cygwin-downloader](http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/Tools/CygwinDownloader/cygwin-downloader.zip)'s bug.

However, there is a workaround...

Just copy `{cygwin-downloader}\setup.ini` file to a `{cygwin-downloader}\x86\` directory. Then reopen `setup.exe`. It will show you a package list without turbulence. You don't need to click `all` from the package list. Just click `Next`.